# How did Arjun conquer sleep ( acquire name gudakesha)and how one can conquer that?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna, yog-nidra

How did Arjuna overcome his sleep cycle and acquire the title -" conqueror of sleep" . What were the process he followed and is it possible to do in this era('kalyug').And if possible then how one can achieve that?! please tell.